# Schengen visa from country with less days of stay

Tags: schengen

Can I apply for a Schengen visa from Germany, enter there and stay for 2 days and go to Poland for 10 days and exit there? As my itinerary is dependent on a friend who's coming from US, I am assuming that this might become the case.

Comment: You should apply from the country which is the main stay in your journey, not in just one that is more convenient. If you can explain that Germany is the more important you can, otherwise apply from Poland.